# to find the range of $\lambda$

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $a, b, c,d$ are positive real numbers such that $a+b+c+d = 2$, then $\lambda= (1+a+b)(1+c+d)$. then $\lambda$ satisfies?
(A) 2$\lt$ $\lambda$$\le3$ (B) 3$\lt$$\lambda$$\le4$ (C)4$\lt$ $\lambda$$\le5$ (D)5$\lt$ $\lambda$$\le6$

what I have tried is $AM \ge GM$ and obtained several equations but I am finding difficulty in proceeding from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the given conditions, you can deduce that $c+d=2-(a+b)$

Now, $\lambda=(1+a+b)(2+(1-(a+b))=(1+(a+b))(3-(a+b))$

Just for making the equation more compact put $a+b=x$
$$\lambda=(1+x)(3-x)=-x^2+2x+3$$

differentiate both sides and equate to zero to obtain the point at which maximum value of the function is obtained.$$-2x+2=0 \implies x=1$$

Plugging this into the equation for $\lambda$, we get the maximum value as $4$

As $0\lt a+b \lt 2$ the lower bound is $3$

Hence $\lambda$ lies between $(3,4]$

NOTE: I felt this method is easier than AM$\ge$GM method so I am including it here.

Comment: @Macavity thanks for pointing it out. I've included it in my answer.

Comment: how did you conclude $0< a+b<2$

Comment: It's simple. We know that $a+b+c+d=2$ and that all of $a,b,c$ and $d \gt 0$. From this obviously $a+b\gt 0$. Now, $a+b$ cannot be $=2$ because then  $c+d$must be equal to $0$, but we already know that $c+d \gt 0$. Which implies $a+b\lt 2$

Comment: thanks from there how did you get  3<$\lambda$

Comment: Just plug in $x=0$ into the equation and you will get the value of $\lambda=3$. But since we know that $x$ MUST be greater $0$, it follows that $\lambda \gt 3$, because if $x\gt0$ then obviously $\lambda$ must be greater than $3$

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot for the explanation

Answer (score 3):

By AM-GM
$$\lambda\leq\left(\frac{1+a+b+1+c+d}{2}\right)^2=4.$$
The equality occurs for $a=b=c=d=\frac{1}{2}$.

Thus, $4$ is a maximum value.

If $a\rightarrow2$ and $b=c=d\rightarrow0$ then $\lambda\rightarrow3$.

We'll prove that it's infimum.

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$(1+a+b)(1+c+d)>3$$ or
$$(1+a+b)(3-a-b)>3$$ or
$$(a+b)(2-a-b)>0$$ or
$$(a+b)(c+d)>0.$$
Done!